# Glowing transparent shader, Eevee and Cycle render different result

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders

I am trying to create a transparent glowing shader. I manage to get the result I'm looking for in Eevee. However, it look different in cycle render. I am aware of the fact where both renderer is different even though a  lot of the node are compactible. So I'm wondering is there a way to replicate the result of Eevee to Cycle. [image]

The image is the result I'm looking for. The model is transparent with a glowing effect.

[image]

A test render with cycle, although there is still some transparency. However, it is significantly weaker.

Is there a way to replicate the effect of image one in cycle ?

The following is the blender file which contain the node setup.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I've been able to manage to getting EEVEE and Cycles to appear the same:

[image: shader]

I've removed the emission shader but enabled emission directly from the cycle shader and then moved the transparent shader to where you had the emission shader.

This doesn't give exactly the effect you were after but it at least matches cycles and EEVEE as closely as possible.  Perhaps it will give you a starting point for what you did want?

EEVEE:

[image: EEVEE render]

Cycles (viewport):

[image: Cycles in the viewport]

For cycles I enabled noise reduction in the viewport render mode:

[image: denoiser on]

Comment: Thank you so much. Even though it is not what what I desire,  It is still a better than the one I create as it is usable in both renderer. I will try to experiment and further improve it .